# How to tell Alexa to punctuate user responses properly. Please see the use case

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, language-model

I am sorry if this looks like a stupid question!

My skill is recording user responses in the database.  This part is working fine. But my concern is Alexa is not punctuating the response at all. Here is an example:

User: **The loading speed of the website is very slow** (a few milliseconds of pause) **can't we make it faster** *(vocal tone was used in such a way so that Alexa can understand that this part is a question)*

Recorded: **the loading speed of the website is very slow can't we make it faster**

Expected: **the loading speed of the website is very slow. can't we make it faster?**

Is there any way to accomplish this? Because it is very important to have correctly punctuated responses to be stored in the database. as this skill will be used for project management purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it's not possible with Alexa. However you can use [AWS Transcribe Service](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/) - build an app for the mobile/web and send recorded audio to the service. According to their docs:

> **Easy-to-Read Transcriptions**
>
> Amazon Transcribe automatically adds punctuation and formatting so that the output closely matches the quality of manual transcription at a fraction of the time and expense.